# Find hire date difference between two employees

Tags: sql

I have an employee table where the fields are:

`first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary, department_id, department_name`, and so on.

I intend to find the hire date difference between `EMPLOYEE1 and EMPLOYEE2`, then `EMPLOYEE2 and EMPLOYEE3`, and so on.

I have to write a query in sql to display the first name and hire date difference of employee

Comment: With dates, it is important to know what database product you are using. Each has its own date manipulation functions.  With sql server, there is a `Datediff`

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: What do you know about Steven and Jennifer that makes them an interesting pair? Is the latter hired after the former with no one hired between them?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Well you see, Steven and Jennifer had an office affair and it's crucial to see how long they've been working together.

Comment: Are you mostly interested in finding the difference in the hire date from the previous row?  Also for this type of question you must specify the database platform (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) as the answer is almost certainly going to be platform-specific.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to calculate the date difference.
e.g

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY),end_date);
```

hope it will help you

also there is also way of using `to_days` function. [click here](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/date_difference.php) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Since you've still not mentioned what RDBMS you are using i'll start with SQL-Server:

```
WITH x 
     AS (SELECT first_name, 
                last_name, 
                hire_date, 
                salary, 
                department_id, 
                department_name, 
                hireNum=Row_number() 
                          OVER( 
                            ORDER BY hire_date) 
         FROM   dbo.employee) 
SELECT DiffDays=Datediff(day, x.hire_date, x2.hire_date),
       first_name, 
       last_name, 
       hire_date, 
       salary, 
       department_id, 
       department_name 
FROM   x 
       INNER JOIN x x2 
               ON x.hirenum = x2.hirenum + 1
```

Comment: In 2012 version, you can do this using `LAG()` or `LEAD()` function.

Answer (score 1):

To find the difference between dates in Microsoft SQL 2012 using days (substitute day with year, hour, etc.):

```
Select datediff(day, HireDate, EndDate) 
From Employee1
```

Comment: Fair enough, I'll delete all the comments to clean it up :) feel free to do the same ^^